# VB.NET Two-dimensional Collection?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, collections

I have a simple doubt but I can't find any information related to this. Is it possible to work with two-dimensional Collections in Visual Basic, or I just have to work with arrays?

In any case, how could I implement either in an array either in a collection, each dimension with a different Type Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list of lists for dynamic lenght of 2nd dimension

```
Dim Lst As New List(Of List(Of String))
```

or two dimensional array

```
Dim Lst()() As String
Dim FixedLst(9)() As String
```

but in either case the final stored object type is still the same.

Do not forget to initialize the list/array object in 2nd dimension to avoid NullReferenceException.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I just found out another solution, using `Tuple`

Comment: Using Tuple is more similar just to List(Of YourOwnDataClassType) when you know the count, names and types of your members.